# jQuery AJAX - get details for failure and insert into DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to jQuery and AJAX and working things out as I go - I have an AJAX call that's working well so far (called from input field in html form). If there was an error with the AJAX call I would like to capture the details for the error and display them on the page in a DIV. I'm not sure how to capture the AJAX error though and can't seem to find a working example that's similar to mine.

Here's my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#storeManager").change(function(){
            var storeManager = $("#storeManager").val();
            $.post('editProject.php', { type: 'storeManager', storeManager: storeManager, id: '1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F' }, function(data) {
                $("#storeManagerRow").addClass("success");
                $("#storeManagerRow").removeClass("danger");

            }).fail(function () {
                $("#storeManagerRow").addClass("danger");
                $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                $("#ajaxAlert").html(show AJAX error response here);
            });
         }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

This is where I would like to display the error text for any AJAX failures:

```
$("#ajaxAlert").html(show AJAX error response here);
```

I can't work out how to get the error response/text - appreciate any guidance or examples similar to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add xhr as a parameter to the .fail function. One of the fields is responseText, which should be whatever you return from the server on failure.

```
}).fail(function (xhr) {
   $("#storeManagerRow").addClass("danger");
   $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger");
   $("#ajaxAlert").html(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use parameters in `.fail()` of [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to get error text, as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#storeManager").change(function(){
            var storeManager = $("#storeManager").val();
              $.post('editProject.php', { type: 'storeManager', storeManager: storeManager, id: '1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F' }, function(data) {
              $("#storeManagerRow").addClass("success");
              $("#storeManagerRow").removeClass("danger");

          }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
              $("#storeManagerRow").addClass("danger");
              $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger");
              //get textStatus
              $("#ajaxAlert").html(textStatus);
              //or use responseText, as
              $("#ajaxAlert").html(xhr.responseText);
          });
    }); 
});
```